# Space taken by fringe in DFS

Tags: artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search, space-complexity

I was recently studying Uninformed Search from [here](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/106105078/pdf/Lesson%2004.pdf). In the case of Depth First Search, it is given that the space taken by the fringe is O(b.m), but I am unable to figure out how(I could not find proof of this anywhere online). Any help or pointers to specific material would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A depth-first tree search needs to store only a single path from the root to a leaf node, along with the remaining unexpanded sibling nodes for each node on the path.
Once a node has been expanded, it can be removed from memory as soon as all its descendants has been fully expanded.
So that, for a state space with branching factor band maximum depth m, depth-first search requires storage of only O(b*m).

ref. Russel & Norvig, Artificial Intelligence, Figure 3.16, p87

Answer (score 0):

The ***Depth First Search*** (DFS) algorithm has to store few nodes in the fridge because it processes the lastly added node first (**Last In First Out**), which results in a space complexity of *O(bd)*. Thus, for a depth of *d* it has to store at most the *b* children of the *d* nodes above.

The ***Breadth First Search*** (BFS) algorithm, however, gets the firstly inserted node first (**First In First Out**). Because of this, it has to keep track of all the children nodes it encounters, which results in a space complexity of *O(b^d)*.
Thus, for a depth of *d* it has to store the children and the children's children, etc., resulting in the exponential growth.